# how to get the nested array count with key values seperated in php

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [res_id] => 1
                    [grand_total] => 303.42
                    [time] => 2016-07-28 11:04:38 AM
                    [status] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [res_id] => 1
                    [grand_total] => 303.42
                    [time] => 2016-07-28 11:04:38 AM
                    [status] => 0
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [res_id] => 1
                    [grand_total] => 303.42
                    [time] => 2016-07-28 11:04:17 AM
                    [status] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

From this I need sub array count i.e., the array having two indexes such as `2 & 1` from this `2 & 1` there are some nested arrays found such as `0 & 1` for each

Here,I need array count as follows

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [count] = 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [count] = 1
        )

)
```

How should I get this..

Someone help me out of this...

Thank you..

Comment: Show us what you have tried in order to achieve this.

Comment: For basic use of Arrays you can review this link also http://www.technofusions.com/introduction-to-arrays-in-php/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very easy foreach your array and use **count** or **sizeof** function.

```
$desiredArray = array();
foreach ($myarray as $key => $value) {
    $desiredArray [$key] ['count'] = sizeof ($value); 
}

print_r ($desiredArray);
```

The output will be as your desired output

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [count] = 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [count] = 1
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, and is better to create new array where you can save count of elements of main array items:

```
$counts = array();
foreach ($array as $k => $values) {
    $counts[$k] = count($values);
}

print($counts); // gives desired result
```

Also you don't need to have extra array for the `$counts` array, what you get is:

```
array (
    2 => 2,
    1 => 1
)
```